# domain redirect to www not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, dns

I have already looked around the internet for this and have tried plenty of things but can not seem to get this working. It was working previously but now I changed my setup and I am directing my CNAME to a no-ip.com address.

My issue is that using www.domain.com will direct to the no-ip.com address but using domain.com will not... I am pretty sure it's because I am using register.com with these domains and it's not allowing me to forward the domain properly... So is there a way I can get this done??

I am using apache

Thanks in advanced. If I left out other information please ask.

This is what my .htaccess looks like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

Options +FollowSymLinks
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Comment: Maybe your .htaccess code?

Comment: I have tried the .htaccess file... I have tried two different ways but no luck

Comment: I mean that you should display your code so others might be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.no-ip.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @D34thSt4lker Are your .htaccess + mod_rewrite enabled? Does it generate an error if you put some junk in the .htaccess?

Comment: mod_rewrite is enabled... and I'm sure my .htaccess is working because my 404 page works

Comment: @D34thSt4lker Do you have `AllowOverride All` set in the config files?

Comment: Yes i do... Anything else?

Comment: @D34thSt4lker Have you made sure it's not inside the wrong scope? For instance within the wrong block. And restarted the server after config changes? Options +FollowSymLinks?

Comment: pretty sure its all accurate

Comment: it should be after 'RewriteEngine on' or before?

Comment: Just put it at the top